# Have Mailchimp survey links go to a specified landing page

Tags: mailchimp

I'm trying to get more info on my newsletter subscribers needs.

I'm using CampaignMonitor currently. It allows me to create a clickable survey (choose one option) that are web links.

I'm considering switching to Mailchimp but their surveys are all links to the same page (*their* confirmation page).

It seems rather trivial for them to allows you to pass in a redirect link.

USE CASE:

Do you use bug tracking software?

[Yes](http://dummy.io)

[No, don't want to.](http://dummy.io)

[No, but I'd love suggestions on how to pick the right one](http://dummy.io)

(I'd like the last option to not only record their vote, but also lead to a landing page where I give them info addressing their choice)

Answer (score 0):

One way that you can redirect your Poll or Survey responders to a custom survey page from the default Mailchimp survey landing page is by putting a meta refresh tag in the page HTML using "Advanced Form Customization". Read the guide here: https://mailchimp.com/help/advanced-form-customization/

Once you get to the HTML code of the survey landing page, simply put a tag like this one in the `<head>`

```
<meta http-equiv="refresh" content="0;url=https://www.example.com" />
```

where the `0` in `content="0;..."` means "wait for 0 seconds before initiating a client-side redirect"

Comment: <meta http-equiv="refresh" content="0;url=http://example.com" />